# Is there a Google+ notificator available as indicator in Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator, google-plus

I think it would be beautiful to have an indicator in Unity tray, counting Google+ notifications (orange on black, like in Google bar). Where can I find it?

Comment: Currently the google+ API seems not to allow access to the notifications. There is a feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=96&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Component) which asks for exactly this API enhancement. So it is unlikely that a desktop application will provide this, as long as the API is missing.

Comment: @xubuntix - that is a good answer - you should post it!

Comment: done :-) and extended slightly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment:

Currently the google+ API seems not to allow access to the notifications. There is a [feature request here](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=96&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Component) which asks for exactly this API enhancement. So it is unlikely that a desktop application will provide this, as long as the API is missing.

The [exceptions to this](http://gplusnotifier.com/en-GB/) seem to maintain a [hidden webkit window](http://awesomium.com/), which is first used to login the user and later does ajax calls to the google+ website plus probably some screen scraping of the result. This is not a straight forward way of handling something that would only require a simple API call in case it was enabled. So most developers will probably wait until the API is updated.